# Samsung monitor changes resolution by itself after 15 minutes

Tags: display, resolution

I am posting this question to get your feedback and help regarding a problem with my Samsung screen. Indeed, my screen does not have the resolution, like if a zoom was applied, I do not see the borders, nor the Windows bar at the bottom.

To fix this problem, I simply changed the resolution using my screen settings, and selected 'Fit to screen'.

But after a few minutes, about 15-20 minutes, the screen resolution changes and becomes zoomed.

Model: `P2270HD`

Model Code: `LS22EMDLU/EN`

Type No.: `EM22TS`

S/N: `EM22H9MZ110763P`

Comment: most TVs have a feature called `overscan`. Try turning this off

Comment: I thought you were talking about your Samsung Smartphone. Now I know it's something with a Windows bar at the bottom. But I don't know if it is a monitor or a TV, nor the model of it.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid can't find this feature of the monitor settings..

Comment: @DanielF the issue appears on my monitor, this is the model: `P2270HD`.

Comment: from the manual "If you use the <Screen Fit> function with HDMI 720p input, 1 line will be cut at the top,bottom, left and right as in the Overscan function" so it seems there might be an overscan function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by doing this:

- Source > HDMI > Tools > Rename HMDI by DVI PC

Now, the 'Screen Fit' is applied and is not disabled after some minutes.